# Css transform 3d

Tags: html, css, 3d, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a CSS opening book, but the transitions doesn't seem to work. 
https://jsfiddle.net/g722fq84/

```
@-webkit-keyframes spincube {
from,to  {                                                    }
10%      { transform: rotateY(-90deg) translatex(60px) translatez(75px)    
 }
```

}

the final position of the cover is fine, but the cover goes right at the beginning, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of translating the div on the x and z axis you can specify a [transform origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

```
.front {
    -webkit-animation-name: spincube;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    transform-origin: left;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/g722fq84/2/

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely forgot the transform origin!